# Astrology: Navamsa and Narayan Dasha - Does Rashi aspect on seventh house indicates marriage possibility in that Rasi period?

Tags: marriage, astrology, rashi

My question is that is this always happen that Rasi dasha (Narayan Dasha) should aspect seventh house in Navamsa to indicate marriage possibility in that Rashi period. For example if someone is running Aries dasha then sign of Aries must have aspect on seventh house in Navamsa to indicate the possibility of marriage during that Rashi dash period

Comment: Yes Dasha of lord of 7th in Navamsa or Dasha of the planets located in it can indicate marriage possibility period.

Comment: That was not the answer I was looking. Suppose as per Narayana Dasha someone is running dasha of Aries. Now Aries in Navamsa aspecting the seventh house. So can we say that the person will get married in Mahadasha of Aries?